# How can I access fcurves for elements that are not objects?

Tags: python, keyframes, fcurves, nurbs-surface

I'm able to access and manipulate individual keyframes (interpolation, handle length, etc) on a normal object's translation/rotation/scale fcurves by storing the fcurve data in this variable, and then running the relevant code on selected keyframes in the Graph Editor:

```
curves = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves
```

However, when I apply the manipulations when selecting keys on an animation fcurve on something like the "Geometry Start & End Mapping > End" value of a Nurbs curve Geometry extrusion, it gives me the following error:

```
Attribute error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'curves'
```

...and calls it out on the "curves" declaration above. Any ideas on why? How do I correctly identify these non-object/action fcurves and manipulate their keyframe attributes?

Comment: Thank you! From the suggested post above I learned that Curves need an additional argument (data) to grab the fcurve: curves = obj.data.animation_data.action.fcurves